# Bash SED string replacement - removes characters before and after Regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have this simple bash (3) script to scan through all the files in the directory and replace some old CSS classes with new ones.

```
export LC_ALL=C

ARRAY=(
    "a-oldclass:new-class"
    "m-oldclass:new-class"
)

for className in "${ARRAY[@]}" ; do
    REGEX=[^a-zA-Z0-9]${className%%:*}[^a-zA-Z0-9]
    CHANGE="s/${REGEX}/${className##*:}/g"

    find src -type f -exec sed -i '' "${CHANGE}" '{}' +
done
```

It is a combination of key:value pairs and a regular expression.
The problem is that it also removes special characters before and after the matching pattern, like:

```
class="a-oldclass" => class=new-class (Quotes are gone)

class=" a-oldclass " => class="new-class" (spaces are gone)
```

I need this outcome:

`class="a-oldclass m-oldclass" => class="new-class new-class".`

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is necessary to avoid this scenario:
I want to replace `a-oldclass` with `new-class`, but I don't want to touch class `data-oldclass`. Since this string contains `a-oldclass` it would be modified. So with `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` I exclude this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Yes, because `"` and `{blankspace}` match `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, they are both non-alphanumeric.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need this outcome: class="a-oldclass m-oldclass" => class="new-class new-class". The current implementation gives class=new-classnewclass. Quotes and spaces are gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the regular expression:

```
REGEX='\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)'"${className%%:*}"'\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)'
CHANGE="s/${REGEX}/\1${className##*:}\2/g"
```

This uses `\( \)` and `\1 \2` to reproduce the matches before and after the classname.

Additionally, I recommend against using all-capital-variables as they may conflict with BASH default variables.

---

In case you also need to match newline terminated strings, you can add

```
REGEX='\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)'"${className%%:*}"'\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)'
CHANGE="s/${REGEX}/\1${className##*:}\2/g"
REGEXNL='\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)'"${className%%:*}"'$'
CHANGENL="s/${REGEXNL}/\1${className##*:}/g"
```

and change the `sed` command to

```
sed -i -e "${CHANGE}" -e "${CHANGENL}"
```

I bet there is a more elegant solution, but this `sed` survived the `-posix` test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. [^a-zA-Z0-9] is necessary to avoid this scenario: I want to replace a-oldclass with new-class, but I don't want to touch class data-oldclass. Since this string contains a-oldclass it would be modified. So with [^a-zA-Z0-9] I exclude this kind of scenarios

Comment: I encounter a problem with .pug extension files with classes defined like .old-class(END OF LINE). It doesn't get updated when no character comes after the string. Could you suggest how can I address this problem?

Comment: You're welcome! Now, before I edit my answer to cover that case, could it also happen that the string is at the beginning of the line?

Comment: The string should at least have a dot in front (To indicate CSS class definition .old-class ). There will always be something in front of the string. So, I think the prefix is not an issue

Comment: OK, try out the edited answer and report back in case it does not fulfill your needs.

Comment: Somehow it fails to change strings, script runs but no affect. I'm trying to debug it

Comment: Hmm after you said it I tried with `-posix` flag and it indeed had no effect. There must be some undefined behavior with the addition and you probably don't have the GNU sed (are you on MAC?). I'm rolling back the answer until I find a solid solution to that.

Comment: I see. I changed it to sed -i '' "${change};${changenl}" '{}' + and works as expected. Many thanks once again!